# Function to return TRUE if cell only has Pure Alpha

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function which identify only the Pure Alpha characters and ignore the Special characters.

And similar to this looking for one more function that is Pure Numeric characters ignoring the special character.

But my code is not doing what i am looking for. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
Public Function IsLetters(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    IsLetters = False
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Not Mid(s, i, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then Exit Function
    Next i
    IsLetters = True
End Function
```

Comment: That's not [how you use RegEx in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)…

Comment: Your Like pattern passes _only_ alphabetic characters,  but your samples pass spaces and (some) punctuation characters too.   Update your like pattern to pass _all_ acceptable characters

Comment: Maybe you mean `If Mid(s, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then Exit Function`, but then you would want to call it `IsNotDigits`.

Comment: Almost all your items at the example starts with a dot, so it seems that dot is an acceptable character. Alpha is not including [SPACE] as character... Should it be included? With it, then you should modify your "like" statement to: "[A-Z.a-z ]", so you will include dot and space.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego, some of the samples include `,` or `-`.  Without clarity from the OP, any suggested pattern is only speculation

Comment: @chris neilsen, it was just an example. It seems that OP want to check something more that special characters. In fact, he/she should explaing which items are returned a not expected value.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego so we're agreed,  the Q needs detail or clarity.

Comment: @chris neilsen. Sure. Already flagged

Comment: @Chronocidal thanks i will defintly go through it.

Comment: @chris neilsen i was looking for the pattern that i was unable to get thourgh Google. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No Digits vs No Letters

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether none of the characters
'               of a string are digits.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsNotDigits( _
    ByVal SearchString As String, _
    Optional ByVal IncludeNullString As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    
    If Len(SearchString) > 0 Then
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To Len(SearchString)
            If Mid(SearchString, n, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then Exit Function
        Next n
        IsNotDigits = True
    Else
        If IncludeNullString Then IsNotDigits = True
    End If

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether none of the characters
'               of a string are letters.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsNotLetters( _
    ByVal SearchString As String, _
    Optional ByVal IncludeNullString As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    
    If Len(SearchString) > 0 Then
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To Len(SearchString)
            If Mid(SearchString, n, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then Exit Function
        Next n
        IsNotLetters = True
    Else
        If IncludeNullString Then IsNotLetters = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working unexpectedly. @VBasic2008